# Passing a variable from ejs file to a javascript file

Tags: javascript, express, web, ejs

I am using express and passing a variable to an ejs file "index.ejs".

```
res.render("index",{passedUser:req.user.alias})
```

I can print it just fine using <%=passedUser%> in the ejs file. However,I need this variable in a javascript file for some operations. Example in the "index.ejs" file if I add-

```
<script>

const a = <%=passedUser%>;
console.log(a);

</script>
```

This doesnot work. Can anyone guide me on how to do this?

Comment: if you're getting value in <%=passedUser%> which is in ejs file. then what's the reason you're not getting value in index.ejs ? I don't understand this. 
Getting value in one ejs and not in another ?

Comment: Apologies,perhaps my question was not clear. I am getting the value in the ejs file but not inside the scripts tag(which is essentially javascript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

`<div id="mydiv" data-user=<%= passedUser %>></div>`

Then in your `<script>`, you can get the value from that div that stored your variable:

```
<script>
  var test = document.getElementById('mydiv').dataset.user
</script>
```

Kind of like that. Good luck.

Comment: This is brilliant! Thanks a ton. Also just to clarify it's document.getElementById('mydiv').dataset-user right?

Comment: I believe it's how I wrote it in my answer. You get the element and then the `.dataset` property stores the `.user` the property you set with the `data-user` part. If you set `data-animal` or `data-city` or whatever, you access it with `dataset.animal` or `dataset.city`.

Comment: Some references: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset and https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp